# Ruby initialization weird argument performance

Tags: ruby, class, initialization

I have a really weird problem.
If we run this class, the execution will be interrupted on the method call due to `binding.pry`.

If we check the value of `receiver` method is `Ivo`, as expected. But the value of `sender is this object, basically the array of params.

```
["Gerard",
 "Ivo",
 #<Bank:0x007fb4339ac2b8
  @accounts=
   [#<Account:0x007fb4339ac240 @bank=#<Bank:0x007fb4339ac2b8 ...>, @founds=0, @user="Gerard">,
    #<Account:0x007fb4339ac1f0 @bank=#<Bank:0x007fb4339ac2b8 ...>, @founds=0, @user="Ivo">]>,
 #<Bank:0x007fb4339ac2b8
  @accounts=
   [#<Account:0x007fb4339ac240 @bank=#<Bank:0x007fb4339ac2b8 ...>, @founds=0, @user="Gerard">,
    #<Account:0x007fb4339ac1f0 @bank=#<Bank:0x007fb4339ac2b8 ...>, @founds=0, @user="Ivo">]>,
 1200]
```

This is the whole class. Any explanation?

```
require_relative './lib/bank'

class TransferAgent
  def initialize(sender, receiver, sender_bank, receiver_bank, amount)
    @sender        = sender,
    @receiver      = receiver,
    @sender_bank   = sender_bank,
    @receiver_bank = receiver_bank,
    @amount        = amount
  end

  def call
    binding.pry
    transfer_result = perform_transfer until transfer_result.succed?
  end

  private

  attr_reader :sender, :receiver, :amount, :sender_bank, :receiver_bank

  def perform_transfer
    sender_account.transfer_money(receiver_account, amount)
  end

  def sender_account
    @sender_account ||= sender_bank.account sender
  end

  def receiver_account
    @receiver_account ||= receiver_bank.account receiver
  end
end

bank_a = Bank.new

bank_a.create_account("Gerard")
bank_a.create_account("Ivo")

TransferAgent.new("Gerard", "Ivo", bank_a, bank_a, 1200).call
```

Answer (score 2):

In your initializer, get rid of the trailing commas. That whole initializer is getting parsed as a single parallel assignment.

A quick demo of what's going on:

```
foo = 1,2,3
foo
=> [1,2,3]

foo = 1,
2,
3
foo
=> [1,2,3]
```